# Django -- How to filter objects with an "author" from a set of "authors"(users)?

Tags: python, database, django, django-models

How to filter objects with an "`author`" from a set of "`author`s"(`User`s)?

The "objects" are `Post`s, having an `author`(`ForeignKey` to `User`).

I'm pretty much stumped by this, so I'd appreciate help with it. Of course one could go about this the naive way, by manually filtering them, but that would hit the database real hard. Thanks anyway.

EDIT:
**Listing of Post**:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    '''A Post or a Status Update.
    '''
    content=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author=models.ForeignKey(django.contrib.auth.models.User, related_name="author")
    tags=models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    replyTo=models.ManyToManyField(django.contrib.auth.models.User, related_name="replyTo")
    # Snip model methods
```

Clarification: I'm trying to filter based upon a set of users and not a single user (which is trivially easy to do)
        when=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

*Thanks to everyone who helped with the previous question. Now I have one final thing to ask:*

**Code excerpt from UserProfile (connected to User)**:

```
def get_updates():
    return Post.objects.filter(author__in=(list(self.friends.all()) + [self]))
```

Is this the most efficient way to get all the posts by an author and its friends? (Note: This is a naive implementation, as it doesn't handle pagination, etc. Will do that later)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Do you want to filter all `Post` objects from a given `Author`?? Or do you want to find a specific `Author` from a list of all `Authors`?

Comment: @rishabh: I think I just clarified that...

Comment: For the newest part of your question, that seems like a fine way to handle it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like:

```
Post.objects.filter(author=user)
```

Where `user` is the relevant user should work, but it's hard to give a good answer with no models

**EDIT**

Now that I understand your question, try this:

```
Post.objects.filter(author__in=users)
```

Where users is the set of users

Comment: @Zach: I added more details... can you help now?

Answer (score 5):

```
Post.objects.filter(author__in=setofusers)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Post.objects.filter(attribute__in = list_of_ids)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Kind Regards.